# RecyclerView customized scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: Horizontal scroll with the above effect]

I want to set the scrolling as above the image. My problem statement is always the right-most image will be larger than the other items of the RecyclerView. the sample code will be helpful for me to achieve my solution.
As an example: after scroll, the next image will be at the right-most position in the bigger size.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LoungeImageAdapter loungeImageAdapter;
//private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private List<LoungeImageModel> imageModelList = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager llm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //prepare image dataset
    imageModelList.add(new LoungeImageModel(R.drawable.a));
    imageModelList.add(new LoungeImageModel(R.drawable.d));
    imageModelList.add(new LoungeImageModel(R.drawable.c));
    imageModelList.add(new LoungeImageModel(R.drawable.d));
    imageModelList.add(new LoungeImageModel(R.drawable.e));
    imageModelList.add(new LoungeImageModel(R.drawable.f));

    //recyclerview setup
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.loungeImageRV);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    llm.setReverseLayout(true);
    loungeImageAdapter = new LoungeImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageModelList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(loungeImageAdapter);
    //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    loungeImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //offset task starts here
    computeHorizontalScrollOffset(mRecyclerView);
}


public int computeHorizontalScrollOffset(RecyclerView recyclerView){//RecyclerView.State
    //llm = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

    int position = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    //RecyclerView.ViewHolder mViewHolder = (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder mViewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    View item = mViewHolder.itemView;

    int y = (int) item.getY();
    if (y < 0) y *= -1;

    if (position == 0) return y;
    else {
        int offset = y;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            //Add your previous item heights to offset
            Log.e("DKS","Ting-tong");
        }
        return offset;
    }
}
```

}

> Below is the adapter class

```
public class LoungeImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LoungeImageAdapter.ImageAdapterViewHolder>{
Context context;
List<LoungeImageModel> imageModelList;

public LoungeImageAdapter(Context context, List<LoungeImageModel> imageModelList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageModelList = imageModelList;
}

@Override
public ImageAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ImageAdapterViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemImageView.setImageResource(imageModelList.get(position).getLoungeItemImage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageModelList.size();
}

public class ImageAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView itemImageView;
    public ImageAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemIV);
        context = itemView.getContext();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i thought that, you are facing image sizing issue. so, i posted the same.

Comment: Your title is so weird  and not matching to your question. Update it ASAP

Comment: @Ahmad, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#computeHorizontalScrollOffset() can you plz see this link. it will be helpful to think about the solution. I am not getting it how to implement it in code

Comment: post your recyclerview code.

Comment: @Ahmad please see the attached code. I am confused where to add computeHorizontalScrollOffset(RecyclerView recyclerView) this function. I mean to say that whether in MainActivity or RecyclerViewAdapter class. and also plz check this function

Answer (score 0):

You always should like below code as your recyclerview item.

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/yourimage"/>
```

Comment: @Ahmad, that is not relevant to the above problem statement. please come up with any other solution.